# Disable page jumping to the top after commandButton is clicked

Tags: jsf-2

I got a `<h:commandbutton>` like

```
<h:commandButton value="Neuer Abschnitt"
styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-info"
action="#{beitragBearbeitenBean.erstelleAbschnitt}" />
```

Well, I click onto the button, the method is called and after that, the page is jumping to the top (provied you are not at the top!)

Interestingly, a

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" />
```

does offer a little jump up.

How can I avoid a jump, generally?

Comment: When you mean jump, is cursor going to start of html document?

Comment: Well, It is just the view. If the button is clicked, the view of the user jumps to the top of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an `<h:commandButton>` doess a full post of the page, no ajax stuff. So it is normal to jump back to the top of the same page (assuming your action returns null or is void). The `<f:ajax>` makes it refresh the form and most likely jumps to the top of the form (if the button you use is also in that form). Updating parts of the form (e.g. a panel inside the form) and not update the button since it can stay ourtside the panel most likely will cause that you stay at the same spot. But if the size of the panel changes, it might not (but then you can e.g. make your pannel scrollable so the button will not move).

Comment: That sounds interesting! I did not know that, thank you! But, I do not want use ajax for this. (See my example of the <h:commandButton>)

Comment: ok... no idea why you would not want that if you want to stay at the same page and same 'location', but it's your choice ;-) Then you have to store the current location somewhere in the server (read it via javascript/jquery and post it to the server) and on reloading the page via some jquery/javascript, restore it. Complex, but it might work (but personally, I'd go for the ajax way

Comment: Well, on the other hand, my commandbutton updates a list for my datatable, and strangely enough, it does not work with <f:ajax ..> in it. I really do not want to ask many questions here.

Comment: Apparently, I was too stupid, to use <f:ajax ..> the correct way. Your answer is the answer for my question, anyway. It works fine with ajax. And without ajax, there is some JS action necessary, I guess. Thank you, again!